# When testing a model written from scratch, how do you predict the new outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Would I use the weights and Biases that's been saved by the training model?

Below is the code. Do I just call in predict with the new test data?? .predict(X_test)

where X is the input array. I am trying to understand the math and how the testing work for neural networks instead of using TensorFlow or Pytorch.

Thanks!

```
class AdalineSGD:
    def __init__(self,eta = 0.01, n_iter = 10, random_state = None,
                shuffle = True):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.w_initializaed = False
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.random_state = random_state
    def fit(self,X,y):
        
        self._initialize_weights(X.shape[1])
        self.cost_ = []
        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            if self.shuffle:
                X,y = self._shuffle(X,y)
            cost = []
            for xi, target in zip(X,y):
                cost.append(self._update_weights(xi,target))
            avg_cost = sum(cost) / len(y)
            self.cost_.append(avg_cost)
        return self
    
    def partial_fit(self,X,y):
        if not self.w_initialized:
            self._initialize_weights(X.shape[1])
        if y.ravel().shape[0] > 1:
            for xi,target in zip(X,y):
                self._update_weights(xi, target)
        else:
            self._update_weights(X,y)
        return self
    
    def _shuffle(self,X,y):
        r = self.rgen.permutation(len(y))
        return(X[r], y[r])
    
    def _initialize_weights(self,m):
        self.rgen = np.random.RandomState(self.random_state)
        self.w_ = self.rgen.normal(loc= 0.0, scale = 0.01,size = 1+m)
        self.w_initialized = True
    def _update_weights(self,xi,target):
        output = self.activation(self.net_input(xi))
        error = (target - output)
        self.w_[1:] += self.eta * xi.dot(error)
        self.w_[0] += self.eta * error
        cost = 0.5 * error**2
        return cost
    
    def net_input(self,X):
        return np.dot(X,self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
    
    def activation(self,X):
        return X
    
    def predict(self, X):
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0, 1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would I use the weights and Biases that's been saved by the training model?

Yes. This happens when you call `.fit()`

> Do I just call in predict with the new test data?? .predict(X_test)

Again, yes

> I am trying to understand the math and how the testing work for neural networks

What happens when we train a neural network? We are finding the weights that best approximate a function that minimises the loss for our problem.

Once you have the right weights, which you do by fitting, you can just pass an input through those weights and get a corresponding output.